# can I make the contenteditable area of my site more sensitive to touch events on android stock browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, contenteditable, android-browser

I found that it's not easy to focus and edit a contenteditable area on android stock browsers.

For example, on the link below http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_contenteditable

If I focus and unfocused and want to focus again, I need to touch and hold on the area for more than a second to get the keyboard up. In contrast, on Chrome for android it is much better, I only need a touch and it would get focused.

Is there any ways in Javascript /jQuery / whatever that can make the area more responsive.

As sometimes people just try to touch it and the keyboard don't show up, then they don't know the area is editable.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can make it another color so people know its editable but it seems some browsers have a longer cooldown in between taps in order to check for a double tap. so maybe there isnt a way to do this but i might be wrong. you can try this http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used this:

```
$('div').on('click', "div[contenteditable='true']", function(e) {                   
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
                //
            } else {
                $(this).focus();
            }
        });
```